# Hay un equivalente en JavaScript puro a este código jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Si alguien me puede orientar, es un boton de "ir arriba" con jquery, quisiera saber si hay un equivalente con JavaScript puro.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var position =$(this).scrollTop();

    // Si el usuario baja el scroll muestro el div qeu contiene el enlace botón
    if (position > 200) {
    $(".boton-subir").fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $(".boton-subir").fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Probablemente sí exista. Qué has intentado?

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API Saludos.

Comment: Claro que sí, [aquí la tienes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll). Y es que jQuery no es otra cosa que una librería basada en Javascript, de modo que todo lo que haces en jQuery deberías poder hacerlo en Javascript puro. Lectura recomendada: [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com).

Comment: De hecho, puedes ver [cómo lo hace](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/89ef81f86f8f371154e9fd3173be5fb57cb72d5e/src/offset.js#L170) jQuery.

Comment: Gracias a todos.